# Algorithms for curve construction

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry, shortest-path, gradient-descent

I am interested in algorithms that construct continuous curves between two points in such a way that minimizes an energy functional of the curve. What sort of algorithms are most used for such tasks?

More formally, given two points $a$ and $b$, and energy functional $E(C)$, where $C$ is a curve such that $C(0)=a$ and $C(T)=b$, I want:
$$ C^*=\arg\min_C E[C]=\arg\min_C \int_0^T E_p(C(t))\,dt $$

Essentially, I'd like a solution to a *variational* curve problem.

I have looked at path-planning, but these tend to be looking at graphs or other paths in discrete spaces.

Another idea is to place points, construct a spline between them, and integrate the energy measure over the spline.
But how can I do gradient descent on the points' positions to iteratively improve them?

Edit (081517): just to clarify some things, thanks to the comments. I am looking for techniques for *curve construction*, where I am given an energy functional $E$ (computed by integrating a point-wise energy $E_p$ over the curve) and two endpoints $a,b$ in a space $M$. It could be a Riemannian manifold, but for now $\mathbb{R}^n$ is sufficient. $E_p$ may depend on derivatives of $C$, as in standard calculus of variations.

In other words, I want an algorithm that does the following:

$$\text{Input: } a,b,E \;\rightarrow\; \text{Output: a curve } C \text{ that minimizes } E(C)$$

For example, let $M=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n=10$, $v:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n} $ be a vector field, $f_i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function, $C(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\gamma_i,\eta_i,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, with point-wise energy:
$$ E_p[C(t)]=\alpha\,\text{div}(v(C(t))) + \sum_i\gamma_i[ C'(t)_i - \eta_if_i(C(t)) ]^2  $$
where $C'(t)_i = \partial_t C_i(t)$ is the derivative of the $i$th component.

My guess is that $C$ should be given in some kind of spline form, i.e. a set of points $P$ with some associated spline parameters $S$. Then we can optimize over $P$ and $S$ to optimize $E$.

Edit (081517)$^2$: based on the comments below, I'm going to look at the ODE defined by the Euler-Lagrange equations of my example function. I get:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial C_k} 
&= \alpha\sum_j \frac{\partial^2 v_j}{\partial C_j^2} - 2\sum_i \gamma_i\eta_i\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial C_k}[\dot{C}(t)_i - \eta_if_i(C(t))]\\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial \dot{C}_k} 
&= 2\gamma_k[\ddot{C}(t)_k - \eta_k\sum_j \frac{\partial f_k}{\partial C_j}\dot{C}(t)_j
\end{align}
So I get a system of $n$ second-order (coupled implicit) ODEs:
$$ \frac{\partial E_p}{\partial C_k} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial \dot{C}_k} =0 $$

Questions:

- How do I solve this for $C$?
- Is there no other standard approach for doing this? (E.g. via optimization)

Comment: This reduces to solving a partial differential equation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Lagrange_equation

Comment: If `E` is arbitrary, wouldn't this be basically all of machine learning?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem with the only difference that instead of using a measure of energy related to the value of curvature along the path I would like using something related to a sort of precomputed distance field in order to prefer paths which avoid obstacles. I was thinking to use B spline or NURBS but the issue remain the same...how to generate control points in the right position to create the best path? I was trying to understand this paper but still don't know if it's actually useful https://dmg.tuwien.ac.at/geom/ig/papers/sig04.pdf if you agree we can speak about it .. d

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft They are both forms of function approximation/construction, but that's where the similarities end :) If you can solve this with machine learning, let me know.

Comment: @Ariel Thanks for your comment. I am aware of the underlying variational problem. The problem with a PDE-based approach is that I am in high dimensions (and sometimes on a manifold)... solving complex PDEs in high dimensions is too computationally expensive (and, I think, unnecessary since I should be able to do some kind of gradient descent on a curve).

Comment: Thanks for that paper! Are you on a manifold? One suggestion is to look at the literature for geodesics on manifolds, e.g. [geodesics in heat](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/GeodesicsInHeat/) or [fast marching](https://math.berkeley.edu/~sethian/2006/Papers/sethian.kimmel.geodesics.pdf). For me, I'm trying to avoid solving PDEs in high dimensions, so I'd like to (as you said) place control points and optimize their positions. :)  [Cross entropy optimization](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/24598/1/p22.pdf) does this and can avoid obstacles ... thoughts?

Comment: Are you acquainted with [variational integrators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_integrator)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you! I was not aware of variational integrators, but they look like they might be very useful! I will look more at it. If you could expound a little on how to use them in this case, I would greatly appreciate it :). I'm not sure what your second comment means; my $E$ is fixed in advance.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $E$ is fixed for a given instance of the problem. It's not always the same, but it's fixed in advance. I've added an example to the question; hopefully that helps! I'm more hoping for a generic methodology though, working for a general smooth $E$ and in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $n<20$ is sufficient (working for a generic manifold would be nice, but not necessary; I'd prefer a simpler approach for Euclidean space over an over-complicated approach for e.g. FInsler manifolds).

Comment: Why not use the Euler-Lagrange equation? It produces an ODE. The endpoints are fixed, so you have a BVP. Then use standard numerical methods.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Because (1) I didn't think of it :) and I thought a differential equations approach would be harder than some kind of optimization one, and (2) now that I see the ODE, I don't really know how to solve it numerically. I've edited the question. Suggestions? :)

Comment: Just pick an $n$, a vector field and functions $f_k$ and try to solve the Euler-Lagrange ODEs with the given boundary conditions. You can also discretize the integral, replace the derivative with a first difference and then try to use gradient descent, but what if the objective function is not convex?

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot add another comment because I am new in this forum. I'm not in Manifold and I would prefer something easier to solve as well. I found this paper quite interesting http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7367853/?reload=true , they use a fast marching method with constrained curvature and headings. In my case I have a constraint on the maximum curvature and also on the starting and target point orientations. I tried to optimize a 3D NURBS knowing that if you fix the first and the last segments of the convex hull on a certain direction you are actually constraining the initia

Comment: Whoever keeps moving Marlene Pinzi's answers into comments (which I am not against on its own) is doing so in a way that cuts off the latter part of the text. Please be more careful (e.g. split it into two comments)!